# Copy values to child Object from Main object

Tags: process-builder, childrecords, parent

I am looking for an option to copy fields from Main Object to Child Object, when lookup is selected:
[image]

Also when i edit field 1,2,3,4 from Child Object i want to copy that value in Main Object field 1,2,3,4.

What suggestion do you have for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some ways to solve it.

If the fields can be editable only in one object, you can use a Formula field.

If you want that these fields will be editable in both objects I suggest you to use a workflow rule, a flow or a Process Builder. Also, if you want to code, you can use a trigger for this.

Comment: I did it with process builder, and i need i first to save record and then after that it update me value in that field( problem 1), can we avoid that? And problem 2 is that i can't edit field...

Comment: If you need to do it before to save, you should use a before update trigger.